# Django ORM: LEFT JOIN condition based on another LEFT JOIN

Tags: python, django, postgresql, left-join, django-orm

I'm using Django 4.0 and PostgreSQL (13.7) as the backend (upgrading would be possible if its required for a solution)

I have two models: `Cat` and `Attribute`.
The `Attribute` holds generic key-value pairs describing `Cat` instances.

`Cat` table:

| PK | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Wanda |
| 2 | Aisha |
| 3 | Thala |

`Attribute` table:

| PK | cat_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | size | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | age | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | size | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | intelligence | 75 |
| 5 | 2 | children | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | intelligence | 60 |
| 7 | 3 | age | 9 |

I'd like to select different attribute values depending on conditions of other attributes for all instances, e.g.:

> Get `size` of a `Cat` if its `age` is greather than `4` or it has more than `2` `children` - or if there is no match, get `age` if `intelligence` is over `50`.

Well, the example here contains random attributes and numbers and does not make any sense, but in my application's world the conditions can be overly complex including several recursive AND, OR, EXISTS and NOT conditions.

My query would be:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(cat.id),
  cat.name,
  COALESCE(
    result1.key,
    result2.key
  ) as result_key
  COALESCE(
    result1.value,
    result2.value
  ) as result_value
FROM cat
-- first condition
LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute cond1 ON (
   cat.id = cond1.cat_id AND (
    cond1.key = 'age' AND cond1.value > 4 OR cond1.key = 'children' and cond1.value > 2
  )
-- second condition
LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute cond2 ON (
   cat.id = cond2.cat_id AND (
    cond2.key = 'intelligence' AND cond2.value > 50
  )
)
-- choose the one or other attribute depending on the first two conditions
LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute result1 ON (
  cat.id = result1.cat_id AND (cond1.cat_id IS NOT NULL) AND result1.key = 'size'
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute result2 ON (
  cat.id = result2.cat_id AND (cond2.cat_id IS NOT NULL) AND result2.key = 'intelligence'
)
```

The result should be:

| PK | name | result_key | result_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wanda | size | 10 |
| 2 | Aisha | size | 7 |
| 3 | Thala | age | 9 |

---

Using Django's ORM I tried the following:

```py
Cat.objects.annotate(
    cond1=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(
            Q(attribute__key="age", attribute__value__gt=4)
            | Q(attribute__key="children", attribute__value__gt=2)
        ),
    ),
    cond2=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(Q(attribute__key="intelligence", attribute__value__gt=50)),
    ),
    result1=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(Q(cond1__cat_id__isnull=False, attribute__key="size")),
    ),
    result2=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(Q(cond2__cat_id__isnull=False, attribute__key="age")),
    ),
    result_key=Coalesce(F("result1__key"), F("result2__key")),
    result_value=Coalesce(F("result1__value"), F("result2__value")),
).distinct("pk")
```

It will fail with the following error:

```
ValueError: FilteredRelation's condition doesn't support
relations outside the 'attribute' (got 
'cond1__cat_id__isnull').
```

Is it somehow possible to construct this or any other query to get the expected results or is this a hard limitation of Django and only using a raw query is the last resort to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you should use `Subquery`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Each table contains several millions of rows, using a subquery for each Cat would result in a dramatic performance issue.

Comment: Currently, I have ~300k cats with 100-200 attributes each, but want to scale to at least 30m cats. I did not added it to the description, as I think that each query should be performant on its own independent of the table size. But thanks nevertheless, that you tried to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using CASE/WHEN statements within the SQL as it seems that the usecase described in my question is not supported by Django (as stated by the error message).

The resulting ORM query would be:

```py
Cat.objects.annotate(
    cond1=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(
            Q(attribute__key="age", attribute__value__gt=4)
            | Q(attribute__key="children", attribute__value__gt=2)
        ),
    ),
    cond2=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(Q(attribute__key="intelligence", attribute__value__gt=50)),
    ),
    result1=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(Q(attribute__key="size")),
    ),
    result2=FilteredRelation(
        "attribute",
        condition=(Q(attribute__key="age")),
    ),
    result=Case(
        When(cond1__cat_id__isnull=False, then=F("result1__value"))
        When(cond2__cat_id__isnull=False, then=F("result2__value"))
    ),
).distinct("pk")
```